# How to access & manipulate my MySQL database which is at different machine

Tags: java, mysql

I've made a Mysql db that i can easily manipulate with Java,

However I cant access it from other machines since its running off localhost only right? How would i go about making it so i would be able to manipulate the data from another machine. Or am i going about this all wrong? I've tried playing around with the remote access on MySQL workbench but I'm just not understanding it.

Here is how I'm accessing it currently.

```
Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampledatabase"
);
```

Comment: You typically would not be manipulating MySQL directly from other machines.  Rather, they would be talking to your Java webapp, which in turn will talk to MySQL.  The reason for this is that MySQL does not (to my knowledge) have a driver which exposes it to the outside world.

Comment: Requires understanding of networking.  If your computer is on the same network as the other machine, then you can substitute localhost with an IP address, or a named host can also work via workbench.  You also need to ensure you have the right ports open.

Comment: @AlbertGil You should read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you could access it remotely!

Firstly, you must understand what's a MySQL user and the authentication mechanism. MySQL treat `'UserName'@'Host'` as a real user who can access to the MySQL server. When you access it locally the actual user you used is `'Me'@'localhost'` (Assume the username here is 'Me'). And inside MySQL server there must be a user named `'Me'@'localhost'` exist(or `'Me'@'%'`). You must provide the right password for `'Me'@'localhost'` as well.

When you need to access it remotely, you must replace `localhost` with the remote ip address so that your app could create the TCP connection correctly. Assume that the ip address of MySQL server is `172.0.1.5` and the ip address of your app is `172.0.1.10`. The actual user you used now is `'Me'@'172.0.1.10'`. You must make sure that the user `'Me'@'172.0.1.10'` does exist in MySQL server. Otherwise you will encounter a auth failure.

To check all users:

```
select * from mysql.user;  // if you have the privilige to perform it
```

Add users: [Create User Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-user.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access the database, which is installed on other machine. You need to understand the url, which you provided

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampledatabase
```

Here `localhost` refers to hostname of the database server, mean same machine or local machine. If you are trying to access some other database server, which resides on other machine, then you need to replace `localhost` with `remote-machine-hostname` or it's `ip-address`.